# How to send json containing (&) via ajax to php script?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to send json data via ajax to a php script but I have the following issue:

This is my html:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-button', function(){
    var myData = '[{"label":"test & test"}]';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'demp.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'name=john&data=' + myData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

And my php:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This is the data I'm receiving:

```
array(3) {
    ["name"]=> string(4) "john" 
    ["data"]=> string(16) "[{"label":"test " 
    ["test"}]"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Regarding the `&` character my json data is interrupted, how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you could try `&amp;` or just simple escape it with a `\&` that what i Would do top of my head

Comment: Also `&` character URL encoded is `%26` so you can try that

Comment: @Breezer — URLs are not HTML, JavaScript, or JSON. Neither of those options will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `data`.

Pass an object instead. jQuery will encode it properly for you.

```
data: {
    name: 'john',
    data: '[{"label":"test & test"}]'
}
```

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) if you want to encode it yourself.